# what mean of *& in void headInsert(DoubleLinkList*& head, int theData) . is it equivalent to void headInsert(DoubleLinkList head, int theData)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm little buggy with the pointers concept.

When I'm trying to work with DoubleLinkList

```
void headInsert(DoubleLinkList head, int theData)
```

this thing is not working. But this is working:

```
void headInsert(DoubleLinkList*& head, int theData)
```

why?

Comment: This is a poor question. What is working and what is not? What are the errors? How are you using these and what does the code look like?

Comment: i m asking about if they r same or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the pointer as reference enables the function to change to which object the pointer is pointing to (this would not be possible when the pointer is passed by value).

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference to a pointer, meaning the pointer is passed by reference. This means changes to the pointer inside the function will still live on when the function returns.

In contrast, when the pointer is passed by value (i.e. without the reference `&`) it's actually copied into a new local variable when the function is called. This means that if the pointer changes, it's only this local copy that changes and the pointer you passed from outside the function will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Read them from right to left.

In the first case `head` is a `DoubleLinkList`.

In the second case `head` is a reference to a pointer to a `DoubleLinkList`.